# Function: require_once error Codeigniter after localhost to server

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am getting error after change `Codeigniter` localhost to server.

```
A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Notice

Message: Array to string conversion

Filename: core/Output.php

Line Number: 661

Backtrace:

File: /var/sentora/hostdata/zadmin/public_html/xx_net/index.php
Line: 315
Function: require_once
```

there is many errors the main reason is `require_once`

```
require_once BASEPATH.'core/CodeIgniter.php'; // line 315
```

i also try to change system path and application but nothing is working
system not generate error log file so i cant find why this error come

Comment: Is this the only thing are you getting in backtrace?

Comment: yes! i don't know the why this error come what i need to do tell me

Comment: project system and application directory same level of index.php or in other directory.

Comment: project system and application both are directory same level of index

Comment: is anyone have solution ??